# How can I compare what a user has typed in the editText with an element of an array that i've created inbuilt in my project

Tags: android, arrays

I have an array of strings and below the array I have a toast that randomly chooses the element from the array and displays it on screen.

In the screen when the toast is displayed the user types in what he has seen as toast into the `editText`.

My question: how do I compare that string in the `editText` to the random element chosen from the array of strings?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: component formatted, typos fixed

Answer (score 0):

You would store the displayed toast string from your array before it displays and then use an if statement to compare the two:

```
//Where you declare your variables and objects @ the top of your class
String toastString = null;
```

In your method that displays toast

```
toastString =  your randomly selected string;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In your compare method

```
String editTextEntry = editText.getText().toString();
if(editTextEntry.equals(toastString)){
    //do something, display something, whatever you need to do
}
else{
    //Strings didn't match
}
```